# Vim fast way to modify method arguments

Tags: vim, vi

One of the most common operation with source code is to modify the method arguments.
Given a method argument list like this:

`("argument1","argument2","argument3")`

I wanna know how to deal with following operations(I use `|` here as a cursor position):

1. When cursor inside a quotes, and you wanna delete the contents inside the quotes.
   like:
    `"ar|gument1"` to `"|"`
2. same as the first one, but delete the quotes.
3. delete all the things in bracket.
   `("argument1","argument2","argument3")` to `(|)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these commands:

1. `di"` (mnemonic: delete iniside `"`)
2. `da"` (mnemonic: delete around `"`)
3. `di(` or `dib` (mnemonic: delete inside `()` pair)

if you want to change the values (i.e. delete and remain in insert mode), use `c` instead of `d`.

For more information, and a lot of other possibilities, check `:help text-objects`.

Answer (score 0):

1. "delete contents inside quotes", `bdw` -- back, delete word, only works if the cursor isn't on the first character.
2. "delete contents and quotes", `F"df"` -- find `"` backwards, delete until next `"` forwards (inclusive). Only works if the cursor isn't on the opening quotes.
3. "Delete all the things in the brackets" -- `%c%()<esc>` -- okay, ugly :) bounce to start of parentheses, change up to the matching parenthesis, and insert two new `()`.